# How to return error message from SQL Server to web page

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am currently working on a project that need to connect with database. The syntax for querying the data in database comes from the user input on a textbox. If the user input for the query produce an error then I need to return the error message from the SQL Server, if there is no error then the result of the query (in this case a `SELECT` statement) will be displayed in a grdiview.

After looking through the web I found that I need to create stored procedure. I never used a stored procedure before so I don't know how to put the retrieving data.

Here is my code so far:

In SQL Server:

```
Create table tbl_dormproc
(
    [ID] int identity(1,1),
    [Name] varchar(150),
    [Date of Birth] date,
    [Address] varchar(100)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE dormproc(@syntax NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'@syntax'
    SELECT NULL
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
END
GO
```

In VB.NET application

```
Protected Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("dormproc", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@syntax", txtQuery.Text)

        drDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dtDatatable.Load(drDataReader)
        Gridview1.DataSource = dtDatatable
        Gridview1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message         
    End Try
End Sub
```

but, it produce an error 'must declare the scalar variable @syntax' inside the gridview.

I have set the `@syntax` parameter in the code above.

So I think the code doesn't read the parameter.

Also why the error displayed in a `gridview` not in `lblmsg.text` ?

What I am doing is to return the error from SQL Server into a label.

For example:

```
select *, from tbl_dormproc
```

it produces a result :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Is it possible to pass the whole query into stored procedure?

Through browsing, so far I only found how to pass a certain column name into stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using sp_executesql correctly.

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dormproc(@syntax NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @syntax 
    SELECT NULL
END
GO
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It produce an error 'Incorrect syntax near '@syntax'.'...

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. You were actually correct, except you don't have to put @syntax in quotes. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah. It's already works. But, the error also displayed in the gridview. Is there any way how to display it on a label. Thanks.

Comment: remove the try catch block from the procedure. then the error will be returned to the error handler in C# and displayed in the error. Please mark this as the error if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

You hasn't unhandled exception in your SP so you can't catch it in your client code. In case of exception in SP your error message just the result set of your SP. You can find it in your `dtDataTable` in first column of the first row.
What about `EXEC sp_executesql N'@syntax'` you should check the syntax. `@syntax` is variable so should use it as:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @syntax
```

Look at the [sp_executesql documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It produce the expected result. Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: But, the error also displayed in the gridview. Is there any way how to display it on a label. Thanks.